# How to resize tabs to browser window size?

Tags: html, css, browser, tabs, resize

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dyjwi/

How can I get the tabbed area to resize when the browser window resizes? I would also like the text to resize as the tabbed area size changes. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a tabbed area. I would also like to note that the SO community is to *help* you fix bugs and code, not to do the work for you.

Comment: I accidentally posted the wrong version of the link, it's updated now.

Comment: that's better, another thing you might do in future questions is post some relevant code.

Comment: I'll do my best to do so in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you are specifying:

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

Which, as the parent of the tabbed content, also becomes the width of the content.
If you want the width of the content to resize with the window, I would change the width to some percentage of the window width:

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

You'd also might use the [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) property to limit the expansion of the content.

I've made an updated version of your [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aHiEd/).